# Loading Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

This is my code so far, and the main problem is that the scripts are sometimes loaded after the main page is loaded, a page is requested with AJAX and uses parseScript on the output, is there a way to make this function pause and not return anything until all the scripts are loaded by the browser?

```
function addScriptTag(src) {
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.body;
    if(node){
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type="text/javascript";
        script.src=src
        node.appendChild(script);
    } else {
        document.write("<script src='"+src+"' type='text/javascript'></script>");
    }
}

function parseScript(_source) {
    var source = _source;
    var scripts = source.match(/<script[^>]*src=[^>]*>/g);
    if (scripts) {
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        src = scripts[i].match(/src=("([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')/);
        src = src[2] || src[3];
        if (src) {
            addScriptTag(src);
        }
    }
    }
    var scripts = new Array();

    return source;
}
```

Comment: could you tried to enclose your script at the end of your html document?

Comment: This isn't an option, the only option currently is adding a callback which I am not familiar with in Javascript, I have got a script in my header that loads pages dynamically with AJAX using custom URLs for bookmarking, there is just 1 page loaded at a time and I use myDiv=parseScript(AJAXFetchedCode) pretty much

Comment: @user1841964: What are you not familiar about callbacks? They should be quite simple for your situation (they are only really hard to use if your code gets too big)

Comment: @missingno I would like to have the callback when the scripts get actually loaded and not just the tags added though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use window.onload or jquery $(document).ready and then call this function inside ? Or call the function at the bottom of the page.